# Can't Find Mac File (Witcher 2 from App Store Save Files)

Tags: macos, mac, file-management, gaming

I need to find the save files for a game I downloaded because now it's loading and saving very slowly. Because it creates a new save file every time you save, I want to go in manually and delete the files from the folder on my computer as opposed to being in the game and deleting them slowly one by one, verifying that I do want to delete each file then waiting for it to delete. The problem is that I cannot find the file no matter what I do. I've looked at support from at least 20 different websites, they all pretty much say that you can simply find the save files by going into your library folder then there will either be the folder "containers" or "com.vpltd.TheWitcher2" but neither of these seem to be the case. i've searched through my Finder window's search bar for "gamesaves" "witcher 2" etc and nothing relevant comes up. So does anyone know a sure fire way to find this file, or had any experience with this file after downloading this game for mac from the app store? It may be because there is no "library" folder after i go to users/rory/ because i changed the way my folders are set up way back. I'm just lost here so any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user Library folder is hidden by default.

Simplest way to find the Library -

- Switch to Finder
  Click on the Go menu
  Hold Option [Alt] - the user Library will appear in the list

Simplest way to get to where you need to be -

- Switch to Finder
   <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>  for New Window
   <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>G</kbd>  for Go To...
  Copy paste this
  `~/Library/Containers/com.cdprojektred.TheWitcher2/GameDocuments/Witcher
  2/gamesaves` including the tilde ~
  Hit  <kbd>Enter ⌅</kbd>

Comment: You're the best!